# ubuntu - get size of directory of empty files

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql, files, ext4

I am testing a flat design to be used instead of sql db, it uses a nested directory structure with files. First I was thinking to store the data inside of the file but it's not more than 40 sign per file, so why bother opening the file when everything can be read from it's name .. but now I can not find out what will be the actual difference in storage space compared to sql table. I tried du and find and it always shows just the directory sizes and 0B for files ..

Is there a way to get the actual size of the files? Or at least calculated them manually, or guess?

Not sure what the filesystem my cloud uses, i guess ext4 .. the OS is ubuntu 14.04

**EDIT:**

From what i understood from the responses the only thing that is going to use disk space is the directory itself. That is minimum of 4Kb. There should be around 300 empty files per directory. If one inode consumes a minimum of 256B that should bloat the directory to 76.8Kb, but the directory is still just 4Kb.

The other thing I am trying to figure out is the difference between sql table and this flat setup. When I executed

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size('table_name'));
```

on the table with 300 records (instead of one string for the name it was 5 fields - 6 with pk: 1x ForeignKey, 1xCharfield max 20 len, 2x FloatField, 1x IntegerField) the response said 16Kb size. This is postgresql 9.3 and django 1.8.6. Can there really be a difference of 60Kb between storing these data in a SQL table and in a empty file's name? Or will the directory not become bloated at all by the inodes and I save 12Kb?

If you wonder why I am thinking so much about a few kb, the setup should later hold up to 100K users with 100x300 of these empty files or db records .. so this is really a question of GB of data .. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If using a file for its name only, leaving it empty, the only thing with a real size is the directory itself.

The key point to understand is that directory are a somewhat special kind of file - a file which can be executed (`cd /dirname`), read (`ls /dirname`) and written/modified (`touch /dirname/filename` and `rm /dirname/filename`).

Generally speaking, adding files into the directory increase the space it uses, while removing files decreases it. However, as directories are a "special kind" of files, filesystems often threat them with specific behaviors.

For more information, you can read [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186813/why-does-every-directory-have-a-size-4096-bytes-4-k) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/713566/what-determines-a-directory-size?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Thanks I read the links and updated my question accordingly. There are still open issues.

Answer (score 0):

you can `cd` into the dir and run `ls -lha`, the one that is called `.` is your local directory. Keep in mind that this approach you're taking will consume a lot of [inodes](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-unixlinux-filesystem-inodes.html)

**EDIT 1:**

You will see the files are 0B in size, but you will be able to see the local folder actually increasing in size as you add files, check the `.` directory, which is the folder where you are placed on.

`Macbook-Pro:/tmp/test$ ls -lha
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   6 DiegoVelez  wheel   204B Oct 26 20:07 .
drwxrwxrwt  43 root        wheel   1.4K Oct 27 09:33 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 DiegoVelez  wheel     0B Oct 26 20:06 file
-rw-r--r--   1 DiegoVelez  wheel     0B Oct 26 20:06 file2
-rw-r--r--   1 DiegoVelez  wheel     0B Oct 26 20:06 file3
-rw-r--r--   1 DiegoVelez  wheel     0B Oct 26 20:07 file4`

Comment: I know something about inodes, read also your link .. but don't see any problem. So what is wrong with consuming a lot of inodes?

Comment: Just tun ls -lha in the directory from what i understand it's still showing zero everywhere: -rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu    0 Oct 26 20:28 2458356.0_2458392.0_10_0_1